# match values of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a collection of records stored if several dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'id':['223','444'],'value_1':['v1','x1']}
d2 = {'id': ['223','666'],'value_2':['v2','x2']}
d3 = {'id':['223','444'], 'value_3':['v3','x3']}
```

I want to search all the records that match the id of the first dictionary and save them in a new one with all the fields, 'value_1', 'value_2' and 'value_3':

```
d_4 = {'id':[],'value_1':[],'value_2':[],'value_3':[]}
```

if one of the records doesn't exist in all the dictionaries I will add '----' in that field. So the output, in this case, will be:

```
d_4

{'id': ['223', '444'],
 'value_1': ['v1', 'x1'],
 'value_2': ['v2', '----'],
 'value_3': ['x3', 'x3']}
```

I wrote this code to do so:

```
for i,id_d1 in enumerate(d1['id']):
    d_4['id'].append(id_d1)
    d_4['value_1'].append(d1['value_1'][i])
    if id_d1 in d2['id']:
        for j,id_d2 in enumerate(d2['id']):
            if id_d1==id_d2:
                d_4['value_2'].append(d2['value_2'][j])
    else:
        d_4['value_2'].append('----')
    if id_d1 in d3['id']:

        for k,id_d3 in enumerate(d3['id']):
            if id_d1==id_d3:
                d_4['value_3'].append(d3['value_3'][j])
    else:
        d_4['value_3'].append('----')
```

But doesn't seems like a good approach.

Comment: Did I understand this right that your records have an `id` member which is in fact a **list of ids**, and a `value_x` member which is in fact a list of values, and each value correspond to an id, in order? That is, `d1['value_1'][0]` is the value corresponding to `d1['id'][0]`?

Comment: This is not clear whether `d1` ids are the reference, because you say "if one of the records *doesn't exist in all the dictionaries* I will add '----' in that field". Does it mean that with `d3 = {'id':['223','555'], 'value_3':['v3','x3']}` you would have had `'----'` in `d_4` for `value_3` AND `value_1` too, then?

Comment: @MathieuBridon Yes, that's correct

Comment: @zezollo I'm taking d1 as reference. Only the records that are in d1 will b added to d_4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

Code:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

# you should use an iterable for your data
in_list = [{'id':['223','444'],'value_1':['v1','x1']},
    {'id': ['223','666'],'value_2':['v2','x2']},
    {'id':['223','444'], 'value_3':['v3','x3']}
    ]

print "Input:\n", in_list

# note that dictionaries are not ordered
out_dict = {}
out_dict["id"] = in_list[0]["id"]
out_dict["value_1"] = in_list[0]["value_1"]

for i,d in enumerate(in_list[1:]):  
    values = [v[1] for v in d.items() if "value" in v[0]][0]
    #print(i, d, values)
    if in_list[i+1]["id"] != in_list[0]["id"]:
        values[1] = "---"
    out_dict["value_{}".format(i+2)] = values

print "Output:\n", out_dict
```

Out:

```
2.7.2 (default, Aug 31 2011, 14:05:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build)]
Input:
[{'value_1': ['v1', 'x1'], 'id': ['223', '444']}, {'id': ['223', '666'], 'value_2': ['v2', 'x2']}, {'id': ['223', '444'], 'value_3': ['v3', 'x3']}]
Output:
{'value_1': ['v1', 'x1'], 'id': ['223', '444'], 'value_3': ['v3', 'x3'], 'value_2': ['v2', '---']}
```

---

Update: fix errors to get required output
Update2: i+1 offset

Comment: If you do need to iterate your variables: `>>> d1 = {"key":None}
>>> i=1
>>> print( locals()["d"+str(i)]["key"] )
None`